# Random Primes Conjecture

Tags: prime-numbers, number-theory

I know it is believed that primes appear to be randomly distributed among the integers.  Is there a formal conjecture or theorem that expressly states that the occurrence of the prime numbers is random?

Comment: Hi @Ollie, While this is related to cryptography, it probably belongs on the https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Maybe_Factor It does, but [this Q/A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421353/are-primes-randomly-distributed) would very probably marked as a dupe. I'll close it though. Welcome, Ollie, but unfortunately questions about prime numbers without a direct relation to crypto are off topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about cryptography but math, where it has a dupe.

Comment: @Maybe_Factor, the reason that I ask this question here rather than at math.stackexchange.com is because if someone happens to discover that the prime numbers are not random what, if any, impact would it have on RSA specifically?  Let's consider that a list of primes can be produced using a formula but without the ability to say what the next prime is given a known prime.

Comment: Then you might want to reformulate your question to ask this directly - it can maybe be then reopened.